# Static functions called twice in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class, react-native

To improve the structure of my app I'm moving most In App Purchase functionality into a special class with static methods and variables.

When I try to use this class **the functions seem to get called twice each, even though in my code I only call them once**. When I debugged it with remote debugging in Chrome and a breakpoint at (1) it did reach that breakpoint twice and both times when I looked at the stacktrace it was called from `componentDidMount()` in `App.js`.

In `App.js` I have this:

```
import IAPManager from "./helpers/IAPManager";
...
async componentDidMount() {
        await IAPManager.prepare(); // (1) debug breakpoint
}

async componentWillUnmount() {
    await IAPManager.endConnection();
}
```

And I also call the methods of `IAPManager` in another component:

```
import IAPManager from "../../helpers/IAPManager";
...
async componentDidMount() {
        const isConnected = await NetInfo.isConnected.fetch();
        if (!isConnected) {
            console.log("Not connected to the internet");
            Alert.alert(
                "No connection",
                "Uh oh, looks like you aren't connected to the internet, which you need to be to take advantage of Premium",
                [{text: "OK"}]
            );
        } else {
            let hasPurchasedPremium;
            try {
                hasPurchasedPremium = await IAPManager.isPremiumUnlocked();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Failed to check if premium is unlocked", e);
                hasPurchasedPremium = false;
            }

            this.setState({ hasPurchasedPremium: hasPurchasedPremium });
            if (hasPurchasedPremium) {
                console.log("Has purchased premium");
            } else {
                console.log("Hasn't purchased premium");
                const premiumProduct = await IAPManager.getPremiumProductInfo();
                this.setState({ premiumProduct: premiumProduct });
            }
        }
    }
```

The `IAPManager` class looks like this:

```
import * as InAppPurchase from 'react-native-iap';
import { AsyncStorage, Platform } from "react-native";

const itemSKUs = Platform.select({
    android: [
        "unlock_premium"
    ]
});

export default class IAPManager {
    static hasUnlockedPremium = undefined;
    static productInfo = undefined;

    static async prepare() {
        await InAppPurchase.prepare();
        console.log("done preparing");
    }

    static async endConnection() {
        await InAppPurchase.endConnection();
    }

    static async getProductInfo() {
        console.log("getProductInfo");
        try {
            const products = await InAppPurchase.getProducts(itemSKUs);
            IAPManager.productInfo = products;
            console.log("finished call to get products", IAPManager.productInfo);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    static async getPremiumProductInfo() {
        console.log("getPremiumProductInfo");
        if (IAPManager.productInfo === undefined) {
            await this.getProductInfo();
        }
        const premiumProduct = IAPManager.productInfo.filter(product => product.productId === "unlock_premium");
        return premiumProduct[0];
    }

    static async isPremiumUnlocked() {
        console.log("isPremiumUnlocked");
        if (IAPManager.hasUnlockedPremium !== undefined) {
            return IAPManager.hasUnlockedPremium;
        }
        IAPManager.hasUnlockedPremium = true; // TODO: remove this when done testing
        return IAPManager.hasUnlockedPremium;
    }
}
```

And finally, the logs I'm getting look like this:

```
05-04 23:58:34.354 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: isPremiumUnlocked
05-04 23:58:34.370 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: Hasn't purchased premium
05-04 23:58:34.370 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: getPremiumProductInfo
05-04 23:58:34.384 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: isPremiumUnlocked
05-04 23:58:34.385 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: getProductInfo
05-04 23:58:34.388 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: isPremiumUnlocked
05-04 23:58:34.403 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: Hasn't purchased premium
05-04 23:58:34.403 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: getPremiumProductInfo
05-04 23:58:34.419 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: isPremiumUnlocked
05-04 23:58:34.422 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: getProductInfo
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: 'finished call to get products', [ { description: 'With premium you can set more than two timers at the same time.',
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     title: 'Unlock Premium',
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     localizedPrice: '19,00 kr',
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     type: 'inapp',
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     currency: 'SEK',
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     price: '19.00',
05-04 23:58:34.424 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     productId: 'unlock_premium' } ]
05-04 23:58:34.426 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: done preparing
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: 'finished call to get products', [ { description: 'With premium you can set more than two timers at the same time.',
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     title: 'Unlock Premium',
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     localizedPrice: '19,00 kr',
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     type: 'inapp',
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     currency: 'SEK',
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     price: '19.00',
05-04 23:58:34.666 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS:     productId: 'unlock_premium' } ]
05-04 23:58:34.668 15867 20588 I ReactNativeJS: done preparing
```

Thanks for reading this far, and I appreciate all help :)!

Comment: Be careful you're calling `setState` inside of `componentDidMount` That could be an issue which is causing a re render and calling it again.

Comment: Also, only set state on those variables you're using in the view. If you're not using them in the view don't make them state. Just make them regular variables.

Comment: Seems like you may be using [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). It double invokes few methods.

Comment: I think you might be right Tomasz, I tried running the production version of my app and it's not showing double invocations of methods. Thanks!

Comment: A related question; Is this the recommended way to run "setup" and "teardown" code for a React Native app? In iOS development I remember putting that kind of code in an `AppDelegate` file which had methods such as `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and `applicationWillTerminate`